# Counting and bounding square-free numbers formed from only the first $j$ primes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> **Definition 1** For any number $x$, $N_j(x)$ is the number of positive integers less than or equal to $x$ that have all their prime divisors among the set of the first $j$ primes $\{p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_j\}$.
>
> **Definition 2** A number is square-free if none of its divisors is a perfect square (except $1$).

- (a) Show that there are exactly $2^j$ square-free numbers whose only prime divisors are in the set $\{p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_j\}$.
- (b) Show that, for all positive integers $x$, $N_j (x) ≤ 2^j\times\sqrt{x}$.
- (c) Show that, for sufficiently large $x$, $N_j(x) < x$. Why does this mean there must be an infinite number of primes?
- (d) For subsequent results, we need a little bit more. Show that for sufficiently large $x$, $N_j (x) < x $.

**What I have thought:**

I really don't know what to do for (a),(c),(d). For (b), can't we show that every positive integer can be written uniquely as the product of a perfect square and a square-free number?

Comment: (a) These numbers are in form $p_1^{\alpha_2}p_1^{\alpha_2}\cdot\dots\cdot p_j^{\alpha_j}$ where $\alpha_k \in \{0,1\}$. Btw, does (c) and (d) differ?

Comment: Is there a typo in (d)? I don't understand the difference between (c) and (d).

Answer (score 1):

(a): Let $A_j$ be the set of these numbers. Then  $A_j$ is in bijection with the power set of $\{p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_j\}$ per $n\mapsto\{\,p\text{ prime}:p\mid n\,\}$

(b): Let $B_j(x)$ be the set of these numbers.  Writing a number $n\in B_j(x)$ as $n=ab^2$ with $a$ square-free, we obtain an injection $B_j(x)\to A_j\times\{1,\ldots,\lfloor \sqrt x\rfloor\}$, $n\mapsto (a,b)$.

(c): For fixed $j$, we can consider $x>2^{2j}$ and find from (b) that $N_j(x)<2^j\cdot \sqrt{x}<\sqrt x\sqrt x = x$. If there are only finitely many primes, we can let $j$ be the number of priems and yet find that there are numbers in $\{1,\ldots,2^{2j}\}\setminus S_j(2^{2j})$, contradiction.

(d) is the same as c.

Comment: What does the \ mean in {1,…,22j}∖Sj(22j),

Comment: Could you provide a more elementary approach to these parts if you can?